# Remove multiple characters from string

Tags: c

I'm trying to creat a program that removes all occurences from a character that I choose from a certain string and also returs the number of characters that were removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIMV 10



int eliminar(char texto[], char ch, char novoTexto[]){
int a=0,i;

for(i=0; texto[i] != '\0';i++){
    texto[i] = texto[i+a];
    novoTexto[i]=texto[i];
        if(novoTexto[i]==ch){
            novoTexto[i] = '\0';
        a++;
        }
}

return a;
}


int main()
 {
 char frase[]="Uma arara torta!";
 char res[50];

 printf("%s\n",frase);
 printf("%d\n",eliminar(frase,'r',res));
 printf("%s\n",res);
 return 0;
 }
```

When I run the program, it returns:

```
Uma arara torta!                                                                                                                                
3                                                                                                                                               
Uma a
```

What I wanted to return is:

```
Uma arara torta!                                                                                                                                
3                                                                                                                                               
Uma aaa tota!
```

It's a silly question but I can't find the mistake that I made. Thank you!

Comment: If you simply replace the character with a `\0` then your string ends there. You have to move the reamainder of the string down one byte, instead of overwriting it. Alternatively, you can simply allocate another block of memory, and only copy the wanted characters there, then copy it back to the original string, which is much easier to implement using `strdup` and `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `'\0'` means to terminate the string there.

You have to *skip* adding characters to eliminate.

Try this:

```
int eliminar(char texto[], char ch, char novoTexto[]){
    int a=0,i,j=0;

    for(i=0; texto[i] != '\0';i++){
        if(texto[i]==ch){
            a++;
        }else{
            novoTexto[j]=texto[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    novoTexto[j]='\0';

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting '\0' means to terminate the string there.
check this:

```
int eliminator(char * texto, char ch, char * novoTexto) {
    int i=0;
    while(*texto != '\0') {
        if (*texto == ch) {
            texto++;
            ++i;
        } else {
            *novoTexto++ = *texto++;
        }
    }
    *novoTexto = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main(int arg, char **argv) {
    char frase[] = "Uma arara torta!";
    char res[50];

    printf("%s\n",frase);
    printf("%d\n",eliminator(frase, 'r', res));
    printf("%s\n",res);   
}
```